# Which Oblivion house will give me the fastest time from fast travel to chests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Pretty straightforward question. Of all the Oblivion houses available to me, which is going to give me the shortest time from when I fast travel to when I have at least 3 safe chests?

Right now I'm using the Imperial City because it's cheap and relatively close to a fast travel location (The Waterfront). But it takes around 20 or so seconds to get there. And everyone knows that 20 seconds is forever when there's one out there with 5!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always look up a mod that adds a house. There are very nice houses, some even add quests. Some make live even more easier but most (at least the ones i tried) are right next to you when using the fast travel map marker.

Here is a list of a couple house mods since it was asked for. There are hundreds out there, most with there own marker on the map. Try to find one that suits your flavor or get them all.

[**Lady stone villa**](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/39113)

[image]

On a steep overlook of the sea, northwest of Anvil, majestically perches The Lady Stone Villa. 
This is a luxurous home filled with tasteful comforts. 
Though a bit isolated, Anvil can be seen from the patio on the upper deck, where you can entertain guests in the evening. 
A hot bath awaits the tired traveler, and there is a pot of stew when you are ready for dinner. 
Relax by the fountain and enjoy the view of the sun setting over the sea.

[**The Possum Lodge**](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/43355?tab=description)

[image]

Hidden in the Great forest, just off the gold road sits Possum Lodge.
It was built thirty years ago (3E 403) by an infamous serial killer who sought refuge
in the Great forest from his bounty...but don't worry, he's dead!

**Hunters Lodge**

[image]

Adds a small cabin/retreat near the ayleid ruin of Bawn, somewhere around Bravil. Perfect for hunters to take refuge and have some rest after chasing down deers. The owner had to leave Cyrodiil and left it for someone worthy to take.

http://oblivion.nexusmods.com/mods/43586/?

[**Carahs Caravan**](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/43464/?tab=description)

[image]

Enjoy the carefree living like Gypsies have for hundreds of years, away from the noisy confusion of dirty, crowded cities. Moonlight reflecting off the White Rose river enhances the mood while you dine by a cheerful fire each evening. Your only neighbors are the animals of the forest when they happen to wander past.

[**Mages sky house**](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/35097)

This mod adds a new player's house to the skies of Niben Bay (east of the city of Bravil).

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, anyway 5 seconds is an eternity if there is a house to travel to in 1 second. So this actually does answer the question.

Comment: "Find a mod" doesn't answer the question at all.  At the very least, provide the name of a mod, as without that, I'm afraid this doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I could list a ton of mods here that add houses with all the discriptions with it. But that is what mod site are for imho. But ok i add to my question again a endless list if you wish.

Comment: I'd highly recommend familiarizing yourself with how Arqade works.  List answers aren't what we want, at all.  All I said was include the name of *a* mod.  Not every single mod that adds a house.  Adding a link after that to the mod repository where you found it is fine.  It needs at least a mod name, though, in order to be of use to anyone.

Comment: I disagree, especially with mods the player itself should look around for what he likes. Anyway these 3 houses have a map marker which you start next to if you fast travel.

Comment: Well, if you want to continue making the list larger and larger, that's your choice.  You're not really helping anyone by doing so, though.

Comment: I am not helping anyone by listing any of the 100's of house mods out there. Everybody has his own thoughts about the game and a home should blend in to that thought. My answer was to look for a mod yourself, most people do not even know or forgot these mods exist. So "look for a mod" is a good answer in addition to the already given answer. Listing 0, 1, 3 or hundred really does not make a difference imho.

Comment: @fbueckert is there a way i could add comments beneath the other answer? Are they to old or do i need more reputation? I'd rather had put this as a comment anyway.

Comment: @MennoGouw: You need 50 reputation to post comments on another answer. It's spam prevention technique. [You can see the list of privileges and their reputation requirements here.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges)

Comment: The thing about Arqade is that we strive to have answers stand on their own, if at all possible.  An answer that amounts to, "Find a mod" helps no one at all, as that's a valid answer to ANYTHING, without providing any details.  An answer that goes, "A mod can help you with this, such as X" provides a solution to the problem.  Turning this answer into, "Here's all the mods that add houses" not only seems pretty passive aggressive, but also doesn't *actually answer the question*.  If you really want to help, you need to at least provide some data pertaining to answering the question.

Comment: @fbueckert Actually, after looking at Menno's original answer, I really like it. I had never considered adding a mod for houses. Once Menno followed your recommendation of naming mods, it actually made the post more fragile at the expense of being only slightly more useful. (This coming from a 47k-rep SE moderator.)

Comment: @corsiKa I disagree.  An answer that does nothing but say, "find a mod" doesn't help anyone at all.  At best, it shows zero research effort, and at worst, can be actively misleading, if no mods exist for the game in question.  Even what's currently here doesn't actually answer how fast it takes to get from fast travel point to the chests.  It's your question, but I seriously question the value of the answer, as it stands.

Comment: @fbueckert Not so. What he's done is do better than answered my question: he's shown that I'm asking the wrong question. He solved my actual problem: reducing the amount of time required to bank my goods to as little as possible. Instead of limiting myself to the ones built in, he suggests crafting the world to suit my needs. If the answer in its present form is bad, it's because it's bogged down by your suggestion of listing mods. Stack Exchange is **not** about answering questions: it's about solving problems. And this answer is very useful, even in its original, abbreviated form.

Comment: @corsiKa We're gonna have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: But there's also a house called White Stallion Lodge [Need to complete quests of the Leyawin Count and Magoza]. This isn't a modded house. Once you fast travel there, it's right in from of you.

Comment: The "Hunters Lodge" mod seems to have been removed from Nexus.

Answer (score 9):

I always used Rosethorn hall, it is a slightly shorter walk and huge advantage against the waterfront house is that you don't need to go to another area for the shops (the less loading screens the merrier :)). This advantage counts for all houses outside the imperial city. However, it is the most expensive house to buy (25,000 gold).

I think, the houses with the shortest walk distances are the Bruma house and Arborwatch (Chorrol). Easiest to buy is the Bruma house.

Worst choise is probably the Leyawiin house, or Benirus Manor.

Comment: What about the chest distances in rosethorn? Are there 3 safe chests immediately at the door I can use? Coming up with 25k isn't a big deal, really. Just want the convenience.

Comment: Theres one chest, a desk, a barrel and some display cases and cupboards on the ground floor. I always used the basement cause it has a lot of chests crammed into a half circle, but that's an extra (quick) load.